# Use header variable in NGINX to forward traffic

Tags: nginx

I am using NGINX (`nginx` Docker image) as a reverse proxy and want to use the `$host` variable in `stream`/`server` context to forward the traffic to specific host which is defined in the `Host` header parameter of the incoming request. The configuration is the following:

```
events {
}

stream {
  log_format log_stream '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol'
  '$status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log log_stream;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  server {
    resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
    listen       127.0.0.1:18443;
    proxy_pass   $host:443;
  }
}
```

There is an error during starting:

```
[emerg] 1#1: unknown "host" variable
```

According to the [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) this variable should be populated. Do you know how can i use it inside the server directive to forward the traffic? Can i use other header parameter with specified hostname/address to forward the traffic?

Comment: What host name? There is no such variable in the stream context. You are just proxying a raw TCP stream. What host header?

Comment: What about this [$hostname](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#var_hostname) variable from the ngx_stream_core_module

Comment: That is the hostname of the system on which nginx is running (or in the case of Docker, the random container name).

Answer (score 1):

Your intention seems to be to pass through TLS connection via nginx `stream` module. If you want to target different destinations depending on the SNI field of TLS header, then you need to use the following configuration:

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $destination {
    host1.example.com backend1;
    host2.example.com backend2;
    default backend3;
}

stream {
    upstream backend1 {
        server 192.168.100.1:443;
    }

    upstream backend2 {
        server 192.168.100.2:443;
    }

    upstream backend3 {
        server 192.168.100.3:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:443;
        proxy_pass $destination;
    }
}
```